# How to use fio to wipe a drive?

Tags: linux, multithreading, dd

I would like to erase drives using fio (flexible I/O tester) instead of dd. Since fio is multi-threaded I believe it would do the wipe/randomized data faster.

```
sudo fio --filename=/dev/sdb1 --rw=randwrite --bs=4k --iodepth=32 --ioengin=libaio --direct=1 --name=randdrive
```

This doesn't work it takes longer than dd and I'm not sure why.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/fio

Comment: Wiping a drive is the mother of all IO limited operations. Why do you think throwing more CPU at it would help?

Comment: Forcing fio to randomly submit tiny I/Os (compared to what a sequential buffered dd will be allowed to do) will cripple its top speed. Also bear in mind fio is doing extra work on each I/O. Something like --rw=write --bs=64k --iodepth=32 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1 should be closer in speed to your dd. Further, you may find your dd speed is even faster with oflag=direct bs=1M . At any rate if you want to securely erase a disk fio isn't the right tool...

Comment: I can tell you from experience that NVMe takes multiple threads to saturate.  Of course if these are spinning disks, then you're not going to see more benefit than about 1 thread per spindle, but then the threads better be interleaving by the raid stripe.

Comment: One more note: SSD's and even modern spinning disks can be erased instantly with "Instant Secure Erase" by wiping/changing the media encryption key, if the drive supports it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: this doesn't make sense.

The limitation when wiping a drive is not how many threads are sending bytes to drive.

To the contrary: assume that you have 5 threads that sent requests in parallel to put data into **different** places of your drive. That means that your drive head is constantly moving. Compare that to a continuous stream of bytes, all going "one after the other". Maybe things are different for SSDs; but heck; when using SSDs, you have no control at all what the device is doing anyway.

In other words: image you are unloading boxes from a truck on some ramp; and there is **one** guy responsible for carrying the unloaded boxes into the building. Does the whole process get faster when you have 5 people putting boxes on each end of the ramp? Nope; because there is still only one guy picking up the boxes, and now he needs to walk **more** to get to all the boxes he is supposed to move into the building.